# TLS 1.2 Upgrade

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Im using a custom form to send to Paypal and take payment. At present I am using the following URLS where the user is directed to, to make payment:  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr for sandbox and https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr for live payments.

I have IPN enabled along with a thank you URL set.

I collect the order info from my ASP net site and when theyre ready i send the transaction to the relevant PP URL (sandbox or Live). The PayPal site is reached, users can make a payment and are returned back to my site.

If i visit https://tlstest.paypal.com/ in a browser from the server where my site is hosted i see PayPal_Connection_OK so this means to me the server is setup but i dont know if any further coding/configuration is required when the form leaves my site to go to paypal to take payments?

I then look in Fiddler and im seeing Tls 1.2 listed on the tunnel to Paypal record.

Do i need to make any further changes to ensure all is setup for TLS 1.2?